# Как запретить делать скриншоты в приложении flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Необходимо запретить пользователю делать скриншоты экранов приложения в flutter.
Проект на androidX, MainActivity на kotlin. Знаю, что нужно копать в сторону FLAG_SECURE, но не очень понимаю как. Кроме того, будет здорово, если подскажете как сделать это на ios!

Answer (score 4):

Смысл от того что вы запретите делать скриншоты, нет никакого. Так как есть другие приложения (и для Android, и для iOS) позволяющие сделать скриншот (и даже запись) экрана другими способами. К тому-же банально можно сфотографировать экран с другого аппарата.

---

*Не тратьте свое время на бесполезные вещи.*

Answer (score 1):

В Android надо примерно так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //prevents from taking screenshot
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); 
}
```

P.S. Не верьте сказкам, о том, что это бесполезно. Есть приложения (через API [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html)), которые снимают скриншот, но требуется разрешение юзера

Comment: **Необходимо запретить пользователю** - его же разрешение этому ведь не помеха?

Answer (score 0):

1. Установка

   flutter pub add flutter_windowmanager
2. Пример

   import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';

   await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);